# Incorrect Datetime value with data format 9/30/2015 6:39:13 PM

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, timestamp

I am trying to import data from a csv data file into MySQL Database. 
My data file has two columns as : `9/30/2015 6:39:13 PM, 52.12366`

In the table I have two columns, one with type: *timestamp* and other with type: *float*.

My table structure is as follows.

[TABLE STRUCTURE in phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVsKq.png)

On insert I get this error stating,

`#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '9/30/2015 6:39:13 PM' for column 'datetime' at row 1`

Kindly help me with this!

Comment: post table structure

Comment: @PathikVejani, I updated the question with the image for the table structure.

Comment: @PathikVejani Can you tell me for such data, what `type` should I set the column to ?

Comment: Check the format of your field and the input format

Comment: @shoghi07 store datetime into unixtimestamp

Comment: @PathikVejani, in phpMyAdmin there is no option for Unixtimestamp. It has DATETIME and TIMESTAMP only.

Comment: @shoghi07 keep datetime field datatype `int` and then store them into unis time stamp

Answer (score 0):

The format of a `TIMESTAMP` column is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` which is fixed at 19 characters.

You have to convert the datetime data to that format or you have to write a script to convert the data while inserting.

Comment: I am trying to import this in phpMyAdmin. 
Can you let me know how to do this in it ?

Comment: May be you can open the csv file using excel like application and modify the datetime format.